# xargs, python, reading files from stdin

Tags: python, xargs

In a directory with 30 CSV files, running:

```
find . -name "*.csv" | (xargs  python ~/script.py)
```

How can I have python properly run on each file passed by `xargs`? I do `print sys.stdin` and it's just one file. I try `for file in stdin` loop, but there's nothing there. What am I missing?

Comment: Answering my own question. The `fileinput` module is where you want to be: http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html

Comment: use fileinput inside your Python script and you don't have to use any shell commands at all.

Answer (score 3):

In fact xargs does not pass to stdin. It passes all its read from stdin as arguments to the command you give it in parameter.

You can debug your command invokation with an echo:

```
find . -name "*.csv" | (xargs echo python ./script.py)
```

You will see all your files outputed on one line.

So in fact to access your files from arguments list in python use this in your script:

```
import sys
for argument in sys.argv[1:]:
    print argument
```

Answer (score 1):

script.py is being run exactly once for each csv file

```
python ~/script.py file1.csv
python ~/script.py file2.csv
python ~/script.py file3.csv
python ~/script.py file4.csv
```

etc

If you want to run it like

```
python ~/script.py file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
```

then do

```
python ~/script.py `find . -name "*.csv"`
```

or

```
python ~/script.py `ls *.csv`
```

(the " may have to be escaped, not sure)

EDIT: note the difference between ` and '